# Copy and paste unknow range into a different worksheet in excel using vba

Tags: vba, copy-paste

I am trying to write a code to copy an unknown number of rows and paste it into a specific location in a separate worksheet. So far I have the code seen below.I Want to copy the data from columns A:F, for an unknown number of rows, and paste it starting in H6.  I get an error in the code "Range("A1", lastrow).Select". The error is "Method range of object worksheet failed".  All help is appreciated.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim copyrange As Range

lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Select
 Range("A1", lastrow).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Final").Select
    Range("H6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to *copy* it (preserving formatting/etc) or would it be OK to just transfer the values?

Comment: it would be okay to just transfer the values if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to debug this, you would dicsover that the value of `lastRow` is `-1`. Get rid of the `.Select` there (and everywhere, for that matter).  You also have an error in your range`.Copy` which I fix:

```
Sub Test()
Dim lastrow As Long

   lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
   Range("A1:F" & lastrow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Final").Range("H6")

End Sub
```

Or, to just transfer the values, I think this will do it (untested):

```
Sub Test2()
Dim copyRange as Range
   Set copyRange = Range("A1:F" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
   With copyRange
       Sheets("Final").Range("H6").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When i run your code i get a type mismatch error on the line "lastrow= Range("A65536").End(xlUp). and when i debug it just turns the line of code that is incorrect yellow and tells me the error type.. i am new to VBA

Comment: Try `Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row` instead, and I revised my answer to this.

Comment: I just highlighted and copied your code exactly and pasted it.  If you would like to look at it exactly as I am i could send you my excel sheet that I am trying to solve it in with sample data.  Both codes have not worked

Comment: Did you see my revision `lastrow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row` ?

Comment: Sorry for making you walk me through it, I'm still going through the growing pains of just starting to use VBA, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem. The error on my end was due to the contents of my test file.  `Range("A65536").End(xlUp)` returns a range object, which caused the mismatch error you had, but on my file, that range contained a value which can be interpreted as `long` data type, so it was not erroring for me (but it was still *wrong* because it was not grabbing the correct Row).