# Grouping cells during a loop not responding as expected

Tags: excel, vba

**Background:**

I have a sheet named *RM* that I am pulling milestone data from to a sheet named *Finance* via a loop (loop is per sheets("RM")).  Once the data is pulled forward, the sheet is supposed to group items in two subtotals:

1)  Group the milestone activities

2)  Group the everything that was pulled over during the loop

Here is the code:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim LR As Long, FR As Long
    FR = Sheets("Finance").Cells(Sheets("Finance").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Finance").Cells(FR + 1, 1).Value = "Raw Materials"
    Sheets("Finance").Cells(FR + 1, 7).Value = Sheets("RM").Cells(12, 2).Value
    For i = 16 To 358 Step 18
        LR = Sheets("Finance").Cells(Sheets("Finance").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Sheets("RM").Cells(i, 4) > 0 And Sheets("RM").Cells(i, 2) = "Fixed" Then
            'Milestone row
            Sheets("Finance").Cells(LR + 1, 1).Value = Sheets("RM").Cells(i, 1).Value
            Sheets("Finance").Cells(LR + 1, 7).Value = Sheets("RM").Cells(i, 4).Value
            Sheets("Finance").Rows(LR + 1).Font.Bold = True
            'Number
            Sheets("Finance").Range(Sheets("Finance").Cells(LR + 2, 1), Sheets("Finance").Cells(LR + 9, 1)).Value = Sheets("RM").Cells(i, 1).Value

            'Removed middle section, which pulls over data from different columns

            'Group Milestone subactivities
            If Sheets("Finance").Cells(LR, 1).Value = Sheets("Finance").Cells(LR - 2, 1).Value Then
                Sheets("Finance").Range(Sheets("Finance").Cells(LR + 2, 1), Sheets("Finance").Cells(LR + 9, 1)).EntireRow.Group
            Else
            End If
        Else
        End If
    Next i
    Sheets("Finance").Rows(FR + 1).Font.Bold = True
    If LR - FR > 1 Then
        Sheets("Finance").Range(Sheets("Finance").Rows(FR + 2), Sheets("Finance").Rows(LR)).EntireRow.Group
    Else
    End If
```

---

**Issue:**

The grouping for the milestone events is not coming over appropriately.  When the code runs, only some of the milestones get their grouping, though the overarching grouping occurs.

In a list of 10 milestones, 1 and 10 do not have milestone grouping, but 2-9 do group.

I thought I had an issue with the if-statement itself, that If LR-FR>2 then, but in stepping-through, I found something weird.

As I step-through with F8, I realized that the data that I .copy/.pastespecial does not show up until after one or two loops have occurred.  The grouping then shows up for the last visually-added data that was pasted.  Then subsequent data shows up until the last bit.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to force the paste to display data?  Is there anything else that would cause this activity from Excel/VBA?

Any help in resolution would be appreciated.

Comment: I would split the task out into 1) copy/ paste, 2) grouping. Once you know it is working the way you want, go back and optimize it. You are reliant on row indexing in the loop and with all the pasting and grouping it would be useful to eliminate that the indices are not reliable during the loop.

Comment: As you're just pasting the values, it would be much quicker (and maybe clearer) to use `_.Value = _.Value` instead of copy/paste values. Since you don't know the size of the copy range, you may want to leverage the `resize` function, as shown in the `Test2` sub in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17241661/3978545)

Comment: @Wolfie I went back and amended to show with output.value=input.value.  Yes, this is cleaner, though I'm still running into the issue that the values aren't showing up during the loop.  Will amend the code in the post momentarily.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie Thanks for that input.  I will give that a shot in a little bit.  I will need to use another loop, but I believe I can get that to work.  Will get back to you once I get that far.

Comment: Check the values actually are what you expect when you're copying them. It's very *unlikely* that VBA is magically not showing results for some loops. There is no delay or asynchronicity in VBA, one action is not done (in this example) before all previous actions have completed.

Comment: @Wolfie The values are what I expect them to be, once they display; I wholly agree that a delay would be unlikely from VBA.  I am unsure why there is the delay in display.  I have decoupled the milestone grouping from the loop and it appears to work quite nicely.  I have added the following to a separate subroutine, which works:     For i = 5 To LR...   If Sheets("Finance").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Finance").Cells(i - 1, 1).Value Then...             Sheets("Finance").Rows(i).EntireRow.Group... Else... End If.  Thanks for the help with a workaround!

Comment: @Wolfie Thought I was good, but this apparently caused a different issue, where the grouping button doesn't show up for certain milestones, though using the 1, 2, 3 buttons up top will group appropriately.  I will post another question for this, if some research doesn't bode an answer.

Comment: ...fixed that issue, too.  Pulled the larger groupings out and moved them to the end, so there was no confusion about what all was to be grouped.  Everything shows up as expected.

Comment: Great, please consider a couple of points of action: **1.** If you think this post will be of value to others, try and add your own answer to how you fixed it which will benefit them, perhaps phrasing your question around what the specific issue was (but not answering *in* the question). **2.** If you think this is a pretty unique issue to you, consider removing the question so it doesn't remain open forever! **--** Glad you resolved your issue, happy coding.

Comment: @Wolfie Was working out a last issue before posting an answer to close the item.  Will accept tomorrow when the timer runs up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things happened to work-around the issue:

1)  I had to add another line so the Milestone groupings did not end on the same line as the Section grouping (in this case, after the loop in the subroutine posted in the question).

```
Dim LR as Long

LR = Sheets("Finance").Cells(Sheets("Finance").Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("Finance").Cells(LR + 1, 7).Value = "-"
Sheets("Finance").Rows(LR + 1).Font.Bold = True
```

2)  I pulled all of the grouping out to the end, after the loops.

The code for grouping ends up looking like:

```
Dim a as Integer

LR = Sheets("Finance").Cells(Sheets("Finance").Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 5 To LR
    If Sheets("Finance").Cells(i, 1).Font.Bold = False Then
        Sheets("Finance").Rows(i).EntireRow.Group
    Else
    End If
Next i
'Group between sheets
a = Sheets("Finance").Columns(1).Find(What:="Not Raw Materials", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False).Row
Sheets("Finance").Range(Sheets("Finance").Rows(4), Sheets("Finance").Rows(a - 1)).EntireRow.Group
```

In the end, I had to make sure the grouping was from the smallest increments to the largest increments to ensure that I did not lose functionality of the mass-grouping (subtotal) toggles.  I would often lose the last milestone's subtotal toggle.